# How to render an svg image in the front of background image on react native?

Tags: image, svg, react-native, background

I want to render an svg image on the 'front layer' of an background image.

When the view loads, only the background image appears, and i don't get any erros. Is the image even loading (at the background of the background)?

Here is what i've done so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import SVGImage from 'react-native-svg-image';


export default class ShowScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
        source={require('../img/image.jpg')}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
        blurRadius={1}>

          <View style={styles.content}>
            <SVGImage
            style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}
            source={{uri:'https://fluent-panda.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/dumbbell.svg'}}/>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});
```

Why the image is not appearing? I am using react-native.

Comment: Perhaps try to add flex: 1; to styles.content

Answer (score 1):

I have my own component to do so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const BackgroundImage = (props) => {

const { container, image } = styles;


return (

<View style={container}>
  <Image
  style={[image, 
    { resizeMode: props.resizeMode,    
    opacity: props.opacity}
  ]}  
  source={props.source}***strong text***
  />
</View>

)
};

const styles = {
container: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,   
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
},
  image: {  
  flex: 1,  
}
};

export {BackgroundImage};
```

that component will fill your container with any image you wish ;)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

class List extends Component {
 render() {
  let source = {uri: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'};
  return (
       <View style = {{backgroundColor: 'black'}>
          <BackgroundImage
           resizeMode="cover"
           opacity={0.6}
           source={source}
           />
           <View style={styles.content}>
        <SVGImage
        style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}
        source={{uri:'https://fluent-
        panda.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/dumbbell.svg'}}/>
      </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
  export default List;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with adding text over map components and it was solved by adding `z-index: -1` to the back element (in this case, the map)